# warble, cannot load such file -- spec/rake/spectask error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jrubyonrails, warbler

I'm very new to Ruby, Jruby and Rails etc. I'm trying to deploy a jruby application to tomcat server using warble. I'm on a windows machine, below is the error I get when I run **warble** from the project's root directory. I did google a lot for the issue, but either the solution didn't work or it wasn't detailed enough for a newbie to understand. Any help or advice is highly appreciated.

```
> warble 

Ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rdoctask.rb
warble aborted!
cannot load such file -- spec/rake/spectask
```

Following are the Ruby gems that are already installed.

```
gem list --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.5)
actionpack (2.3.5)
activerecord (2.3.5)
activeresource (2.3.5)
activesupport (2.3.5)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
diff-lcs (1.1.3)
hoe (3.3.0)
i18n (0.4.0)
io-console (0.3)
jruby-jars (1.7.0)
jruby-rack (1.1.10)
json (1.5.4)
minitest (2.5.1)
rack (1.0.1)
rails (2.3.5)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.9.4)
rspec (2.12.0)
rspec-core (2.12.0)
rspec-expectations (2.12.0)
rspec-mocks (2.12.0)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
test-unit (2.5.2, 1.2.3)
warbler (1.3.6)


jruby -S gem list --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.9)
actionpack (3.2.9)
activemodel (3.2.9)
activerecord (3.2.9)
activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.2.2.1)
activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter (1.2.2.1)
activeresource (3.2.9)
activesupport (3.2.9)
arel (3.0.2)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.2.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.1)
jdbc-mysql (5.1.13)
journey (1.0.4)
jruby-win32ole (0.8.5)
json (1.7.5 java)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.19)
multi_json (1.3.7)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.9)
railties (3.2.9)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12)
sprockets (2.2.1)
test-unit (2.5.2)
thor (0.16.0)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.12)
tzinfo (0.3.35)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `jruby -S warble`

warble is pointing to the default ruby

your default ruby is not set to jruby.